# Comparing the current and next element in a list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have a list of `QTableWidgetItems` via `pyqt` and I want to check if the rows of these elements are all in succession of each other, otherwise I would need to error-handle. I tried:

```
for i in list(selectedItems):
    if ((i+1).row - i.row) != 1:
        print("Selected Items are not succeeding each other")
```

And I tried to use `itertools.cycle` with no avail. Any leads?

Edit: Ok, so here is a bit more info. My first proposed solution will get me the error Message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QTableWidgetItem' and 'int'
```

And when using a cycle I could no find a possibility to reach the 'QTableWidgetItem.row()' method.
What I want is a simple function that will check if the difference in rows stays at 1 for all the elements I have currently selected, otherwise it means there are items selected which have a "gap" between them which my code currently cannot handle.
When that case happens I will simply disable the grouping function until the selection falls within my criteria again.

Comment: Perhaps something like `lst = list(selectedItems); for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]): print(a, b)`?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? What should happen when two elements are not in succession of each other? What's your question exactly?

Answer (score -1):

```
# iterate through the list
for i in SelectedItems:
     # Use an if statement to check for difference between current
     # and previous item is 1
     if selectedItems[i-1] - i != 1:
        print("Selected Items are not succeeding each other")
        break  # stop if this happens in any two items
```

There are a bunch of things which will throw this off. But without access to the list/data-types I don't think I can put statements to handle them.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: what happens when you reach the last element of the list?

Comment: @bananenpampe it is checking with the previous item.

Comment: `SelectedItems` does not match `selectedItems`, and Python for loops do not give indices by default.

Comment: This is basically what I have tried as well but unfortunately I am handling objects and not integers and therefore cannot use simple arithmetic functions here.